# Why are statistical approaches used in Physics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, nuclear-physics

Statistical analysis is the analysis of a very large number of particles / sample space where the general behaviour and trends of these particles is studied. But this also means that its probabilistic. That is, the properties of individual particles may and most definitely will deviate from the general trends. As in nuclear fission and calculation of their half lives. It doesn't seem to be possible to know whether a nucleus will split or not.
And most of kinetic theory and thermodynamics seem to be statistics. The individual particles are way weirder.

So why, even though a lot of deviations from the general trend exist, statistical analysis is still used? Is it really impossible to analyze the individual particles?

Comment: Yes - even if it were possible in principle (as it is in classical mechanics) how would you go about describing the motion of $6\times10^{23}$ particles in a mole of gas (even if you neglect internal motions, since each "particle" actually has structure)?

Comment: @NickD Well, the computation powers of modern super computers have drastically improved. Is it still not enough to do such an analysis?

Comment: @evamPUNdit : $10^{23}$ is a _huge_ number. How would you even store the initial conditions of your system, let alone determine its evolution?

Comment: So it's a practical impossibly to do such a computation.

Comment: It is indeed practically impossible. But even if it was doable, what would you do with answer? Extracting useful information from that amount of data is non-trivial. (unless you do the obvious thing at look at average values, but then what have you achieved that could not have been done with a statistical approach?) And then there is a similar problem with the inital conditions. How are you going to measure the initial positions of all those particles so you know how to start your simulation?

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have understood the reason for using a statistical approach, and its more than just a practical impossiblity

Comment: @evamPUNdit, you also mentioned thermodynamics in your post.  Since temperature is a big idea in thermodynamics, and temperature is necessarily defined in a statistical sense, thermodynamics will be statistical in nature.

Comment: statistical approaches are also used in physics to deal with signal-to-noise issues in experiments where the anticipated signals are very small...

Comment: @DavidWhite I'm only familiar with high school physics so I'm unaware of many of the(important) definitions in more advance physics. As such I only knew that temperature is associated with a system, not the way it was defined

Comment: @evamPUNdit, temperature is defined as the average kinetic energy of a large number of atoms or molecules.  Because of this, temperature has no meaning for a single atom or molecule.

Answer (score 0):

I want to address this:

> . As in nuclear fission and calculation of their half lives. It doesn't seem to be possible to know whether a nucleus will split or no

This is even worse than classical statistical mechanics which ends up in probabilities because of large numbers and the boundary conditions needed.  Fission and all of nuclear physics are in the realm of  quantum mechanics which is inherently probabilistic, even with one nucleus, and there is no way to even imagine overcoming this, at least in main stream theories.